# Android - fixed header over scrollview with pull to zoom effect

Tags: java, android

i am currently rewriting our app from ios to android and I couln't get a proper effect to work. So in iOS we used the [this library](https://github.com/maxep/MXParallaxHeader) to achieve the fixed header over the content scrollview with parallax effect. I quickly modified the example and export it as a gif so it's more clear what we're trying to achieve:

[image: ios]

So first of all I tried something with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` where I came across [this](https://gist.github.com/zly394/6387f735d4161c625a06f5595c5cb8cd) snippet. So basically the snippet adds a `AppBarLayout.Behavior` what achieves the zoom effect. Overhaul it does not feel smooth.

Next I found [PullZoomView](https://github.com/Frank-Zhu/PullZoomView) which seems popular in android. The zoom and the scroll behaviour feels great. The only problem is that the header is not fixed and gets overscrolled by the listview like this:

[image: android]

So I dig into the code and tried to modified it for my propose but it seems hacky and complicated.

So it seems like from what I saw in all libraries that this overscroll over the header behaviour is more in common. Does someone has any advice how can I achieve the behaviour like I want before I write my own solution? Is there any library maybe which I don't found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a solution by my own right after I submit this question. I really liked the concept in the library from iOS that you can have individual UIViewController for the header and for the content part so in Android it seems that Fragments are the way to go here. I want to share my code if anyone want to have the same effect:

[image: illustration]

Add the following dependencies to yur `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.4'
implementation 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
```

My class (sorry it's a bit messy):

```
public abstract class ParallaxHeaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks {

    private ObservableScrollView scrollView;
    private LinearLayout headerView;
    private FrameLayout contentView;

    private int headerHeight = 0;
    private int minimumHeaderHeight = 0;

    protected void setContentView(int layout, Fragment header, Fragment content){

        super.setContentView(layout);

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
                .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

        headerHeight = (int)convertDpToPixel(260, this);
        minimumHeaderHeight = (int)convertDpToPixel(160, this);

        int contentViewId = View.generateViewId();

        contentView = new FrameLayout(this);
        contentView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        contentView.setPadding(0, headerHeight, 0, 0);
        contentView.setId(contentViewId);

        scrollView = new ObservableScrollView(this);
        scrollView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        scrollView.setScrollViewCallbacks(this);
        scrollView.setFillViewport(true);
        scrollView.addView(contentView);
        scrollView.setScrollViewCallbacks(this);

        IOverScrollDecor decor = new VerticalOverScrollBounceEffectDecorator(new ScrollViewOverScrollDecorAdapter(scrollView));
        decor.setOverScrollUpdateListener(new IOverScrollUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOverScrollUpdate(IOverScrollDecor decor, int state, float offset) {
                if (offset > 0) {
                    // 'view' is currently being over-scrolled from the top.
                    update((int)-offset);
                }

            }
        });

        rootView.addView(scrollView);

        addFragment(contentViewId, content);

        int headerViewId = View.generateViewId();

        headerView = new LinearLayout(this);
        headerView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, headerHeight));
        headerView.setId(headerViewId);

        rootView.addView(headerView);

        addFragment(headerViewId, header);

    }


    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(int scrollY, boolean firstScroll, boolean dragging) {
        update(scrollY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownMotionEvent() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {
    }

    private void addFragment(int id, Fragment fragment){

        final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(id, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

    }

    private void update(final int scrollY) {
        headerView.getLayoutParams().height = Math.max(headerHeight - scrollY, minimumHeaderHeight);
        headerView.requestLayout();
    }

    public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
        return dp * ((float) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    }

}
```

In your Activity you can call it like:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main, new HeaderFragment(), new ContentFragment());
```

**fragment_content.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ContentFragment">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="@string/lipsum"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_header.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/example"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't directly answer your question but I made a library that has a component which expands on click/touch. I think you might be able to use the code to create your own scrollbar header thing.

https://github.com/NadavTasher/ToolLibs/blob/master/lightool/src/main/java/nadav/tasher/lightool/graphics/views/ExpandingView.java

e.g. Make the fixed view your header, and the expanding view your scrollview